# Excel 2010: Scroll autmatically to the next cell when the cell is copied

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

While doing some kind of copy paste task this thought came to my mind. Actually i am copying one cell and pasting into some other application and again i need to copy the next cell and paste it. This goes on. I have some 15-20 rows which i need to paste it some 100 times. So each time i need to manually scroll to the next cell then copy and then paste. Instead, is there any way if i copy the cell the cursor should automatically scroll to the next cell and at the end it should scroll back to the first. I am using Excel 2010.

Any useful reply is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this Sub in VBA and associate a button to it:

```
  Sub CopyAndMove()
      Selection.Copy
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
  End Sub
```

Hope this helps.